# Why cannot I cast to immutable in @safe functions? (D)

Tags: casting, d, immutability

Why cannot I cast mutable variables to immutable values in @safe functions? Also, is there a workaround for this?

```
@safe pure immutable(char[][char[]]) getNameValuePair {
    immutable(char[])[immutable(char[])] pair;
    // logics filling the pair here
    return cast(immutable(char[][char[]])) pair;
}
```

This code will cause the compile error:

> Error: cast from immutable(char[])[immutable(char[])] to immutable(char[][const(char)[]]) not allowed in safe code

When I do `return pair.idup`, I get the error: `no property 'idup' for type 'immutable(char[])[immutable(char[])]'`.

Comment: Please provide an example of what you are trying to do. Also please read this: http://dlang.org/const3.html . Especially the last example where the author casts a mutable argument into an immutable. It is a good question anyway, so +1 for it. :)

Comment: @DejanLekic I added an example to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The purpose of @safe is to verify memory integrity, casting is a command to ignore safety and "do what I say." I'm not sure what work is being done to identify "safe" casts.

A workaround is to use @trusted, but ultimately you're just doing it wrong. Your function is pure, so it is able to assign into an immutable instance:

```
void main()
{
    immutable(char[][immutable(char[])]) ans = getNameValuePair();
}

@safe pure immutable(char[])[immutable(char[])] getNameValuePair() {
    immutable(char[])[immutable(char[])] pair;
    // logics filling the pair here
    return pair;
}
```

Note that the type which comes out has the key as an immutable(char[]) and not a char[] which you were trying to cast to (thus breaking the guarantees of the pure/immutable type you declared). In other words, thank the type system for correcting your mistake.

Answer (score 2):

because @safe assume that something immutable cannot ever change, aka it tries to ensure the invariant holds

however with casting you can circumvent it:

```
char[] str = "somestring".dup;
immutable immutableStr = cast(immutable) str;
//now immutableStr == "somestring"
str[0]='S';
//now immutableStr == "Somestring"
```

if you are using it for simple arrays and slices then you can use idup which creates an immutable duplicate

Comment: Isn't immutable supposed to guarantee no instance of the data will get changed?

Comment: yeah there isn't a idup for associative arrays, sorry. also the `cast` keyword circumvents many safeties in the language and assumes that the programmer knows what he is doing (meaning many uses are `@unsafe`)

Comment: So there is no way to work around it? It's kinda stupid it works this way as there are no mutable references anymore to the array. (The function is pure)

Comment: @JeroenBollen there used to be an AssumeUnique that allowed the cast to immutable but I can't find it in the library

Comment: @JeroenBolle, `@safe` is there not just for simple data, but (more importantly IMHO) for complex data types to ensure immutability (integrity) of data.